# MySql - Performance com 0% de eficiência

Tags: desempenho, mysql

Meu MySql está muito lento nas consultas, mas essas mesmas consultas feitas no servidor de produção são rápidas. Então mexendo aqui achei essa tela conforme circulado em vermelho diz que a eficiência está em 0% e no produção está com 99.8%. Tem como aumentar a eficiência na minha máquina? Será que alterando o arquivo `my.ini` resolveria?

[image: screenshot da minha máquina]

Segue meu arquivo `my.ini`

```
[client] 
port            = 3306 
socket          = "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
[mysqld]
port= 3306
socket = "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
basedir = "C:/xampp/mysql" 
tmpdir = "C:/xampp/tmp" 
datadir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
pid_file = "mysql.pid"
key_buffer = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 32M
table_cache = 64
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
log_error = "mysql_error.log"
plugin_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data/lib/plugin/" 
skip-federated
server-id   = 1
innodb_data_home_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M
innodb_log_file_size = 5M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50
character_set_server=utf8
join_buffer_size = 256k
thread_cache_size = 9
flush_time = 0
default-storage-engine = InnoDB
open-files-limit = 4110
tmp_table_size = 30M

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
[isamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout

[client] 
port            = 3306 
socket          = "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
[mysqld]
port= 3306
socket = "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
basedir = "C:/xampp/mysql" 
tmpdir = "C:/xampp/tmp" 
datadir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
pid_file = "mysql.pid"
key_buffer = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 32M
table_cache = 64
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
log_error = "mysql_error.log"
plugin_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data/lib/plugin/" 
skip-federated
server-id   = 1
innodb_data_home_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M
innodb_log_file_size = 5M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50
character_set_server=utf8
join_buffer_size = 256k
thread_cache_size = 9
flush_time = 0
default-storage-engine = InnoDB
open-files-limit = 4110
tmp_table_size = 30M

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]

[isamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

**Edit**

Abaixo a tela do produção com 99.8% de eficiência. Peguei no momento em que as consultas (*SELECTS*) estavam em zero.

[image: screenshot do servidor de produção]

Comment: Você tem zero SELECTs por segundo, imagino que por isso ele não tenha como medir a eficiência de uso dos seus índices (que acredito ser o que aquele número quer representar).

Comment: Esta pergunta está na fila de análise de fechamento como "fora do escopo". Seja lá quem for que ache que esta pergunta deveria ser fechada, poderia explicar melhor? Eu pessoalmente acho que não há nada de errado com esta pergunta.